# Using Vim commands in a Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, vim

so im trying to create a bash script that runs on MAC command line to a remote server and uses some mv commands to move some files around but i also need it to open up a file and add a line to the top of the file and save it in the middle of the script heres what i have so far:

```
(this is adjusting permissions so i can edit the file)
chef-client -r xxxxxxredactedxxxxxxredacted
cd /xxx/postgresql/xx/main/
Sudo chmod -R 775 filenamehere
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres filenamehere



read -p 'Enter the IP: ' ip


echo "Enter the file name :"
read -r filename

  echo "Type this below: host all all "$ip"/24 trust : "
read -r line

cd /etc/postgresql/12/main/
printf '1i\n%s\n.\nwq\n' "$line" | ed "$filename".   <-- **this is the problem line**


^ this command gives me permission denied because of access, for some reason i can edit it with vim but not this command

its worth noting these commands arent ran through my pc so my ability to move files is somewhat limited, its ran through SSM ing into an IP of a test enviroment through my command line

Normally I manually VIM into the file and add a line to the top
```

Comment: `vim` is not intended to be used programmatically. There are lots of more basic utilities for manipulating files.

Comment: I would use `ed` for this: `printf '1i\n%s\n.\nwq\n' "$line" | ed "$filename"`.

Comment: (If the commands look vaguely familiar, that's because `ed` inspired `ex`, which inspired `vim`.)

Comment: As has been said before, `vim` is not designed to be remote-controlled. You could use `sed` instead, but since all you want to do insert a single line on top of a file, this is something you don't need to even think of an editor; you could use `cat` to create a new file, consistin of your `$line` and the content of your old file appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if you're using echo to output the prompts because you didn't know about the `-p read option` or you wanted the new lines.

You could use command grouping to add a line at the top of your file.

```bash
read -p "Have you copied a file to the data shipper? (yes/no)"

if [ "$REPLY" == "yes" ]; then
    read -p "Enter a variable: " VARIABLE
    
    read -p "Enter a file name: " FILE
    
    cd /var/xxxredacted////
    cd /tmp/
    sudo mv "$FILE" /varxxxredactedxxxxxxxx/drop
    cd /var/redactedxxxxredactedxx/drop
    sudo unzip "$FILE"
fi

read -p "Enter the file name:\n" FILENAME
read -p "Enter the line to be added:\n" LINE

{ echo $LINE; cat "$FILENAME"; } > "${FILENAME}.new"
mv "$FILENAME"{.new,}
```

`sed` could be used too, if the line had to go to a specific line :

```bash
# If \n is omnited, $LINE will just be inserted on 
# line 1 instead of appending a new line
sed -i "${LINENB}s/$LINE\n/" $FILENAME
```

Comment: seems like some of these commands get denied permissions within the remote server, sudo vi filename works however

Comment: @GMob, which commands are being denied ? Can you provide the error message ?

Comment: @tterixeira
after i do printf '1i\n%s\n.\nwq\n' "$line" | ed "$filename" trying to add a line to the top of a file i get :

1417
pg_hba.conf: Permission denied
?
?

I have to !wq in vim to override the write only file

Comment: Well, it's not the code provided above.

Comment: I highlighted it above, im ust trying different methods of editing a read only file

Comment: That's because you changed the file permission to :  775 which result in rwx for owner/group and r-x for others. What you want is to use the 776 permission.

Comment: so using CHMOD -R 777 should work?

Comment: @GMob yes although it's not recommended for potential security issue. You should use 770 and run your script as postgres user or a user in the postgres group.
You also don't need to use ed nor vim. Take a look at the code I provided in my answer.

Comment: I get permission denied on the 770, can i do 777 edit it and then change the permission back to 775 without risk?

Comment: You got permission denied because you are not the right user. `sudo -u postgres ./your_script_name` should work, even with a 770. Although you have to know postgres user's password.

Comment: But yes, you could chmod 777 then 770 or 774. I would recommand 774 so you can still read the file without being postgres user.